# Turning off scikit-learn's warnings when using n_jobs > 1

Tags: python, scikit-learn, suppress-warnings

I can turn warnings off with scikit-learn with several options, using the `warnings` library:

```
# After the imports
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore')
# Or in the code
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore") 
    # do stuff
```

But this doesn't work on a classifier as soon as the n_jobs parameter is higher than 1 (due to the multiprocessing ?). The following code sample illustrates this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import warnings
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()

for n_job in [1, 2]:
    print("START")
    print("n_jobs =", n_job)
    clf = OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression(solver="liblinear", multi_class="ovr"), n_jobs=n_job)

    x_train = np.array([[1,1], [0,1], [0,0], [1,5], [2,1], [3,1]])
    y_train = np.array([[False, False, True], [False, False, True], [True, False, False], [True, False, False], [True, False, True], [True, False, False]])

    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
        clf.fit(x_train, y_train) # "UserWarning: Label not 1 is present in all training examples."
    print("END")
    print()
```

Output:

```
START
n_jobs = 1
END

START
n_jobs = 2
UserWarning: Label not 1 is present in all training examples.
END
```

How can I disable warnings even when n_jobs > 1 ?

EDIT: Since it might be related to `multiprocessing`, I might add that I ran this script on linux, with python 3.6.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your warning, can you please cross check.

Comment: I double checked, are you using linux & python 3.6 ?

Comment: windows n py 3.6

Comment: Surely why you don't get the same output, multiprocessing on windows has nothing to do with linux.

Answer (score 0):

Found same issue, and the answer is embedded here
[How to silence all sklearn warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53968004/how-to-silence-all-sklearn-warning?rq=4)

in addition to warnings ignore, also use os to set the PYTHONWARNINGS variable

```
import warnings
import os

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
os.environ['PYTHONWARNINGS'] = 'ignore
```