# Speed up cross validation in SVM scoring

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, cross-validation

I want to get the accracy, average_precision, F1, precision, recall and roc_auc scores

I do realise that using the code below, I'll get the average_precision, the problem is when running this code it takes about 20 minute to show the results, is there a better way to get all the scores above in a shorter amount of time ?

`clf_svm_2_scores_avg_precision = cross_val_score(clf_svm_2, np.array(x), data['link'], cv=5, scoring='average_precision')`

Answer (score 0):

Cross validation is generally long, as the training/validation process is generally done several times and then a mean of the scores is calculated. You may try to add the argument `n_jobs`, in which you have to set the number of cores of your computer.

Comment: this is helpful, thank you! i also found out, if you want to get multiple score you can pass in a alist of all the scores in the scoriing param

Comment: Now i'm getting UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no predicted samples. 'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for), the result of all of them is 0, any idea on how to fix this ? Thanks

Comment: What did you try in order to fix the second issue ?

Comment: I quit didn't tbh, I added the average param and set it to 'micro' then switched it to 'macro', this way I got different results, way better than 0.0

Comment: Just check if all labels in y_tru appear in y_pred, as indicated in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162506