# Undefined Metric warning when running federated learning simulations

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am getting this undefined metric warning error: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior. During my FL simulations

Due to the error warnings the precision, F1-score, and recall results are low

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably related to this: [UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162506/undefinedmetricwarning-f-score-is-ill-defined-and-being-set-to-0-0-in-labels-wi)

You probably have labels in your test set, which do not appear in your generated predictions for the same set.